# Based on ACF and PACF, select orders p and q of the ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have plotted the act and pacf of the transformed data for 'unemp'. I need to find the orders of p and q for the ARIMA(p,d,q) model. The PACF appears to tail off, but the ACF does not tail off or cut off. I am not sure now to get the p and q orders for this model and have not seen an ACF that looks like this.

[image]